# count different value in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I try to count a data with integer datatype in a table

I used the query below

```
SELECT sesi_ujian,hari_ujian,COUNT(DISTINCT sesi_ujian) AS jumlah FROM ujian_mhs
```

It works, but return 1 result like this
[image: the result of query above]

and in my table, there are 5 different "sesi_ujian" values, such as :
[image: data]

can you tell me how to display the counting result of "sesi_ujian" ?

Comment: use group by sesi_ujian.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your SQL for it, is wrong. try following

```
SELECT DISTINCT sesi_ujian,hari_ujian,COUNT(id) AS jumlah FROM ujian_mhs group by sesi_ujian
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for only distinct values count. Use the below query.

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT sesi_ujian) FROM ujian_mhs
```